# Proving that the solution of ${\rm arg\,min}\,\|W-HH^T\|_F^2$ is the same as the solution of ${\rm arg\,max}\langle W,HH^T\rangle$

Tags: matrices, quadratic-programming

Assume a binary matrix $A\in\{0,1\}^{N\times K}$, where $K\leq N$, and there is one and only one non-zero element in each row of $A$, i.e., $A1^{K\times 1}=1^{N\times 1}$. We obtain a matrix $W=AA^T$.

To recover $A$ from $W$, we relax the binary constrain in $A$, and use $H\in [0,1]^{N\times K}$ denote the relaxed matrix, and try to obtain $H^*$ using the following two formulations:

1)\begin{align}
H_1^*=\ &\mathop{\mathrm{arg\,min}}_H \|W-HH^T\|_F^2\\
\text{s.t.}\quad&H\in[0,1]^{N\times K}\\
& H1^{K\times1}=1^{N\times 1}
\end{align}

2)\begin{align}
H_2^*=\ &\mathop{\mathrm{arg\,max}}_H \langle W,HH^T \rangle\\
\text{s.t.}\quad&H\in[0,1]^{N\times K}\\
&H1^{K\times1}=1^{N\times 1}
\end{align} 
where $\langle A, B \rangle=\sum\limits_{i,j} A(i,j)B(i,j)$.

Are the solutions to the two optimization problem, i.e., $H_1^*$ and $H_2^*$, equivalent? If yes, how to prove it?

Answer (score 1):

Hints: Let $B=HH^T$. Use the following identities and the constraints in your optimization problem. Try to prove that every feasible solution in first one is a feasible solution in second one and vice-versa
$$||A||_F^2 = \operatorname{trace}(A^TA)$$
$$<A,B> = \sum_{i,j}A(i,j)B(i,j) = \operatorname{trace}(A^TB)$$
$$||W-B||_F^2=\operatorname{trace}((W-B)^T(W-B))=\operatorname{trace}(W^TW)-2<B,W>+\operatorname{trace}(A^TA)$$

Comment: May be A in the last row should be changed to B?

Comment: @GehenHe right. Just did that.